# How to fix 'empty file after run mysqldump with task scheduler'

Tags: mysql, batch-file, windows-task-scheduler

I am trying auto backup for mysql, and i write .bat file, it working (Only there is a warning in cmd "Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure").
After, i try set up win task scheduler for start .bat file. When i did it, it is working but backup file coming empty.
How can i fix this file ?

That's my .bat file content

> @echo off
>   mysqldump -uusername -ppassword db_name > "backup_path\backup.sql"

Comment: What makes you say it is working?

Comment: Where do you specify the MySQL server address?

Comment: try `> "%~dp0backup_path\backup.sql"`

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit mysql in localhost, it is working because create file, but it is empty

Comment: @GerhardBarnard when i click manuel it's working, so it can see path

Comment: Did you try what I asked?

Comment: Yes, i did it. I writed already full path, and i tried what your said but this time, file didn't create anywhere. That's my full path: >mysqldump -uroot -p12345678 bitnami_redmine > "C:\Users\hakan\Desktop\redmine_backup\redmine.sql"